# Override plugin file in sage wordpress

Tags: wordpress, roots-sage

I am trying to override plugin file located in `path/filename.html.php` by sage theme ,

I have moved the file under `themedirectory/path/filename.html.php` but that did not show anything
The sage version used is 10

DO anyone has an idea about that?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the Wp File Manager plugin and find your plugin file and then replace your file...

Comment: No I can't user other plugin , this method will destroy update